# UITapGestureRecognizer not working in UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiimageview

I had the following code:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *showStoryTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showNewsStory:)];
[showStoryTapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[self.storyImageView_ addGestureRecognizer:showStoryTapRecognizer];
[showStoryTapRecognizer release];
```

This however doesn't trigger the showNewsStory, why is this? I have enabled userInteraction in the image view.

Comment: is the ImageView in a tableview?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *oneTouch=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(OneTouchHandeler)];

[oneTouch setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];

[imageView addGestureRecognizer:oneTouch];

imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 80):

You should enable user interaction for `UIImageView` object:

```
[self.storyImageView_ setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

---

#### EDIT:

Try to remove the

```
[showStoryTapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
```

I don't think `UITapGestureRecognizer` has its delegate methods as far as I know.

Comment: @xonegirlz actually, I thinks the code what you gave is fine (except the one I pointed out above). Maybe one of subviews covered the `storyImageView_`.

Comment: @Kjuly  [self.storyImageView_ setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
 this was helpful. but UIGestureRecognizer is the super class of UITapGestureRecognizer, so we can set delegate when ever UIGestureRecognizerDelegate required.

Comment: That's the real answer. Rest of them did not work for me, except this one.

Comment: @voghDev glad it helps :)

Answer (score 16):

`UIImageView` has user interaction disabled by default, unlike most other `UIView` subclasses in UIKit.

Comment: UILabel has it disabled as well.

Comment: Wasted a lot of time on this. Thank you. That checkbox is hidden away nicely ;)

Answer (score 7):

I also noticed that in swift3, if you are adding a gesture recognizer which also looks for the target and the target is usually `self`, then you have to make the UIView to which you are adding the gesture recognizer to be a `lazy var`. Otherwise the gesture recognizer won't work. I think this is a bug in swift3. Ideally if you are accessing self in a variable before the class is fully initialized, it should throw an error. The code below won't detect gesture recognizer.

```
let messageImageView: CachedImageView = {
    let iv = CachedImageView()
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    iv.layer.cornerRadius = 16
    iv.layer.masksToBounds = true
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    iv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let zoomTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleZoomTap))
    zoomTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    iv.addGestureRecognizer(zoomTap)
    return iv
}()
```

To fix that, you have to use `lazy var`

```
lazy var messageImageView: CachedImageView = {
    let iv = CachedImageView()
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    iv.layer.cornerRadius = 16
    iv.layer.masksToBounds = true
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    iv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let zoomTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleZoomTap))
    zoomTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    iv.addGestureRecognizer(zoomTap)
    return iv
}()
```

Comment: That's a very helpful observation! I guess this happens because `self` doesn't yet exist when this method is called, so the gesture recognizer has no target.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, we should use `lazy var` instead of `let` to make sure `self` does exist when you tap it.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe ... `action:@selector(showNewsStory)` instead of  `action:@selector(showNewsStory:)`  .
Please check it .
Are there any other `UITapGestureRecognizer` in this controller ? 
Try this:

```
otherTapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

Comment: That's okay, if the selector is wrong, it'll lead a crash of EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Answer (score 3):

If you have already set `imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;` but the action still doesn't fire. Maybe it's because for one of superviews of imageView userInteractionEnabled is NO;

Answer (score 2):

objective-c ios 10

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *oneTouch=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(OneTouchHandeler)];

[oneTouch setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];

[imageView addGestureRecognizer:oneTouch];

imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

// swift 3.0

```
   let oneTouch = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.OneTouchHandeler(_:)))

imageView.addGestureRecognizer(oneTouch)

imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 2):

add

`storyImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;`

Answer (score 0):

if you allowed 2 different gesture, you should add below code snippet. For example, you use pickerView and also you want to detect tap gesture for same pickerView.

> Asks the delegate if two gesture recognizers should be allowed to recognize gestures simultaneously.

**Objective C**

```
    -(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    return true;
}
```

**Swift**

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    use lazy var instead of let . Here is an example.

    lazy var loginSignUpView: LoginSignUpView = {
            let lsv = LoginSignUpView()
            lsv.loginRegisterButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLoginRegistrationButton), for: .touchUpInside)
            lsv.segmentedControlForLoginRegister.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSegmentedControlForLoginRegister), for: .valueChanged)
            lsv.profileImageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSelectProfileImageView)))

            return lsv
        }()


@objc func handleSelectProfileImageView() {
        print("Image tapped")
    }
```