# Creating an irregular UIButton in Swift where transparent parts are not tappable

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a pie chart where each sector is a separate button with a background image, but UIButton has a rectangular shape and all the buttons overlap. Is there a way to make a UIButton the exact shape of an irregular image (in Swift) so this does not happen?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can use `UITapGestureRecognizer ` in image like [THIS}(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552184/uitapgesturerecognizer-not-working-in-uiimageview#11559340, instead of use UIButtons

Comment: This is probably better answer than overriding `-containsPoint:` or `-hitTest:`  on multiple UIButtons in this case.  Just make it one view and do that math on that view to react appropriately to a touch. (Only if for some reason you really need the behavior/semantics of a UIButton should you consider going down that road)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UIBezierPath or CGPath to define your pie chart sections and use their [containsPoint:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009276-CH1-SW40) or [CGPathContainsPoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPathContainsPoint) to detect touch

Answer (score 1):

As I'm concerned, may be the `CAShapeLayer` is better way to achieve the pie chart. By doing that, you can use

```
[layer hitTest:]
```

method to deal with the touch action.

Comment: How would you use hitTest with CAShapeLayer in Swift?